# The most secure server data transfer?

Tags: linux, security, file-transfer, transfer

I'm running an Ubuntu Server somewhere, 24/7. It's used to host a webpage, a shoutcast radio, some other stuff. I'm planning to buy a Raspberry Pi 1B to use it as a "backup" server, in the following way :

- Whenever the Raspberry Pi is powered up and connected to the internet, it checks if the server is online (by pinging it)
- If it is, it copies *via internet* a precise folder from the server and backs it up on the Raspberry Pi drive. Then the Raspberry Pi powers off / reboots once the transfer is completed.

As you can see the "via internet" part is emphasized, as I **don't know** which data transfer method to use to make this the most simplest / stable (easy to automatize via shell scripts, not going to crash or fail) and more secure (no one can intercept and read the data which is transferred between the two machines) way. If it's slow, no problem, just want it done via automated script.

So what's the best way to do that ? WGET a HTTPS page of the server from the RPi with some credentials ? Automated SFTP ? Third-server-based transfer ? Anything else ?

Edit : People seem to **downvote** this post. This is fine, but I'd really appreciate to know why, so don't hesitate to comment if you disapprove to tell me what I did wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use rsync for that kind of stuff.

How to use rsync:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-rsync-to-sync-local-and-remote-directories-on-a-vps#how-to-use-rsync-to-sync-with-a-remote-system

It also works with ssh-keys so you do not need a password which makes it great for backups.